# UPDATE database and update where variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question in regards to the GET function. I currently have a form with a get action. I am accessing that data in another page with the get function. Unfortunately, I have been getting an "error: undefined index" on every one of my values. After reading up on similar problems, I tried using isset (as seen below) and it gets rid of the error, but I am not sure that my data is stored in the variables at all because if I echo the 4 variables, nothing shows up. Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

Data from form:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div class=\"addform\"><form method='GET' action=\"update.php\">\n";

echo "  <input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['tfid']."\" name=\"tfid\">\n";

echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"fname\"      value=\"".$row['fname']."\"/>\n";

echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"lname\" value=\"".$row['lname']."\"/>\n";

echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"hca\" value=\"".$row['hca']."\"/>\n";

echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"file\" value=\"".$row['file']."\"/>\n";

echo "  <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/update.png\" alt=\"Update Row\" class=\"update\" title=\"Update Row\">\n";

echo "<a href=\"delete.php?tfid=".$row['tfid']."\"><img title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/delete.png'/></a></form></div>\n";

}

echo "</table><br />\n";
```

and the code for retrieval:

```
$tfid= isset($_GET["tfid"]) ? $_GET["tfid"] : NULL;
$fname = isset($_GET["fname"]) ? $_GET["fname"] : NULL;
$lname = isset($_GET["lname"]) ? $_GET["lname"] : NULL;
$hca = isset($_GET["hca"]) ? $_GET["hca"] : NULL;
echo $tfid;
echo $fname;
echo $lname;
echo $hca;
```

Comment: How are you setting those `$_GET` variables on the first page?  Through a form?

Comment: If a `$variable` is NULL, echoing it outputs nothing...

Comment: yes, I am setting those get values through a form. I'll edit my question above to show that.

Comment: @kayle Please show the HTML output of the form, not the server side code that built it

Comment: @Evan:
are you asking for the error messages or something else?

Comment: @kayle I was asking if you could post what the above code *produces* - just the raw html if you view-source of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## After your edit:

After you posted your form code, I noticed the problem may be that the values of your inputs may be empty, as the syntax looks more or less correct. Double check the values via `view-source` to ensure their validity.

---

**Before your edit:**

The errors are ocurring because the variable in fact is *not* set. Make sure your form looks like this:

```
<form action="yourpage.php">
<input name="fname" type="text" />
<input name="lname" type="text" />
<input name="hca" type="text" />
<input name="tfid" type="text" />
</form>
```

As shown above, the `_GET` variables are looking for the *name* attribute. A common mistake among beginners (everyone has been guilty of this at one time or another) is the use of `id` in place of `name`. `id` is used for selector purposes whereas `name` is often used to retrieve values on the server side.

**Something to keep in mind....**

As @George Cummins mentioned, you should also be aware that `$_GET` parameters are passed through the URL like so:

```
http://yoururl.com?var1=data1&var2=data2
```

In some cases, you may not want the user to see all of the data being sent through your form, so in this case you would want to use `$_POST` which is essentially *a hidden passing of the form's data*. In reality, this data is not truly hidden but it certainly is more hidden than the use of `$_GET`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Additional troubleshooting can be accomplished by looking at the URL parameters of the target page. GET requests show fields and data in the URL.

Comment: You are correct that by using the get function, the variables should be coming through in the URL. I cannot seem to make that happen, as much as I'd like to :)

Comment: @Evan:
The idea is to be able to hit a button and do an update on the data stored within the form. the loop creates the next row of data that can be entered. If any of the fields are changed, I can hit the update button and they are changed in the database.

Comment: @kayle Then please show me what the form looks like, do you have this on a live site anywhere? Or, if not, could you please post the HTML that is produced from the above code?

Comment: @Evan: Could you tell me how I could post this? I do not want to add the output to my original question, and people seem to get angry when posting code to the comments section.

Comment: @kayle Just add a small portion of the output to the original question. I just want to see if the values of inputs are what you think they are.

Comment: You know, when you asked me for the html output, I actually ended  up spotting the problem. You were right, the "name = " field was not coded properly. I am now seeing variables in my url. I thought that "value" meant the same thing as "name", but I see now how they are different. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @kayle That's what I figured would happen, it seemed like a simple mistake. Take it easy, and good luck.